# CodeIgniter4 + Vue + Webpack devServer CORS

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, cors

I am poking around with Vue & CodeIgniter 4 and am using as https://github.com/flavea/ci4-vue a jumping-off point.

No matter what I seem to try, I keep getting this pesky CORS error when in dev mode:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://example.com/public/api/book/get'
>   from origin 'http://example.com:8080' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
>   check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource.

- This is my CodeIgniter URL: http://example.com/public/api/book/get
- This is my WebPack/Vue URL: http://example.com:8080

I've read quite a few threads and [Mozilla's article on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) ...I understand

1. What CORS is,
2. That the CORS issues is likely due to my PHP app running on port 80 and my Vue/Node/Webpack App Running on Port 8080 in dev mode.

What I don't understand where I need to resolve it...Apache, my PHP App, Vue, Webpack? (my suspicion is WebPack / Node).

My question ...how do I resolve this CORS issue for my dev mode?

Some additional background info:

- I have everything set up, but am running into issues when I run the site in dev mode, (i.e. `npm run dev` ...I have no issues when I run it in 'production'; i.e. `npm run build`).
- The above reference codebase uses [CodeIgniter 4](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4) for the API URLs; in other words, I am using CodeIgniter for RESTful URLs to do CRUD stuff on a MySQL / MariaDB database.
- I'm running my site on MAMP / macOS (Apache, port 80 )for my CodeIgniter app
- From what I gather, the dev build uses [WebPack's devServer](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver) when in dev mode (see below)

  ```
  const devWebpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
      module: {
      rules: utils.styleLoaders({ sourceMap: config.dev.cssSourceMap, usePostCSS: true })
      },
      // cheap-module-eval-source-map is faster for development
      devtool: config.dev.devtool,

      // these devServer options should be customized in /config/index.js
      devServer: {
      clientLogLevel: 'warning',
      historyApiFallback: {
          rewrites: [
          { from: /.*/, to: path.posix.join(config.dev.assetsPublicPath, 'index.html') },
          ],
      },
      // I added the following, seems to do nothing.
      headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token"
      },
      hot: true,
      contentBase: false, // since we use CopyWebpackPlugin.
      compress: true,
      host: HOST || config.dev.host,
      port: PORT || config.dev.port,
      open: config.dev.autoOpenBrowser,
      overlay: config.dev.errorOverlay
          ? { warnings: false, errors: true }
          : false,
      //publicPath: config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
      //proxy: config.dev.proxyTable,
      quiet: true, // necessary for FriendlyErrorsPlugin
      watchOptions: {
          poll: config.dev.poll,
      }
      },
      plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env': require('../config/dev.env')
      }),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(), // HMR shows correct file names in console on update.
      new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
      // https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          filename: 'index.html',
          template: 'index.html',
          inject: true
      }),
      // copy custom static assets
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
          {
          from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
          to: config.dev.assetsSubDirectory,
          ignore: ['.*']
          }
      ])
      ]
  })
  ```
- In my .htaccess, I've added

  ```
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>

  <FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
  ```

Comment: Adding headers on the dev server won't do anything - if that was where the requests were going they wouldn't be cross origin. Are you planning to deploy this as two apps?

Comment: Well, my plan is to use the aforementioned CodeIgniter 4 + Vue project as a jumping off point; so I'm not really sure where that will lead me in terms of deployment. Essentially, I want to use CI4 as a RestFul API and do most of the front-end work via Vue.

Answer (score 1):

After trying a bunch of things, I had to add headers to my CodeIgniter Method:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent CORS errors in your local dev environment and access data from other web servers (remote or local), it can be very easily done with the proxy config. This option redirect every request to a local path to a remote URL. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy

You don't even need a CORS configuration in this case, because you'll mount an external path on the same local environment, so that the web browser does not complain. The remote address must of course be trustworthy.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm not clear on what would need to go in the proxy in my case.

This is my CodeIgniter URL: http://example.com/public/api/book/get
This is my WebPack/Vue URL: http://example.com:8080

Comment: How do you call the API in your code in production? With an absolute URL to the remote address or is it a relative address? For example, if you have the front-end on the root path (`example.com/`) and the back-end beginning with `/api` (`example.com/api/`), you probably have relative paths in your front-end which request e.g. `/api/users/123`. In this case, you could define a proxy config where everything under `/api` redirects to `https://example.com/api`. If you define it like this, a call to `localhost:8080/api/users/123` returns the response of `https://example.com/api/users/123`.

Comment: You could also mount your back-end on `localhost:8080/api` and strip the api part away in the the actual remote request (e.g. `localhost:8080/api/users/123` returns `https://example.com/users/123`). See the webpack documentation for that.

Comment: If you still decide for CORS, be aware that you should not define `localhost` as an allowed origin if the server is in production (that's probably what caused your CORS problem), because it is a security issue. You also don't have the possibility to share cookies with a remote server via CORS, but it works with a webpack proxy config, because the browser is not aware of that (webpack abstracts the remote connection).